# New Ubuntu 14.04 on thinkpad e145 bluetooth not working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, broadcom, thinkpad

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a brand new Thinkpad E145 and am trying to use a bluetooth wireless mouse. I cannot pair it because Ubuntu cannot discover it. I have tried most of the solutions that I found on Google but have had no success. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: [Bug #1283003 - Bluetooth + 14.04 Bluetooth headsets are not working after last couple of updates](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1283003)